# Manipulating Json object literals

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with json object literals in javascript. Starting from my original json

```
[{"group":"sample 1","name":"FC_TOT","value":6},
{"group":"sample 1","name":"PPC","value":88},
{"group":"sample 1","name":"PRO_OX","value":6},
{"group":"sample 1","name":"POLY_TOT","value":6}],

[{"group":"sample 2","name":"FC_TOT","value":9},
{"group":"sample 2","name":"PPC","value":8},
{"group":"sample 2","name":"PRO_OX","value":7},
{"group":"sample 2","name":"POLY_TOT","value":7}]]
```

I need to re-sort this based on the name and assign value to each group. The new json should look like

```
[
    {
        "group": "FC_TOT",
        "sample 1": 6,
        "sample 2": 9
    },
    {
        "group": "PPC",
        "sample 1": 88,
        "sample 2":8
    },
    {
        "group": "PRO_OX",
        "sample 1": 6,
        "sample 2": 7
    },
    {
        "group": "POLY_TOT",
        "sample 1": 6,
        "sample 2": 7
    }
]
```

where the new group is the name from the original json. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to build array and inside one `forEach()` loop to loop objects.

```js
var data = [[{"group":"sample 1","name":"FC_TOT","value":6},{"group":"sample 1","name":"PPC","value":88},{"group":"sample 1","name":"PRO_OX","value":6},{"group":"sample 1","name":"POLY_TOT","value":6}],[{"group":"sample 2","name":"FC_TOT","value":9},{"group":"sample 2","name":"PPC","value":8},{"group":"sample 2","name":"PRO_OX","value":7},{"group":"sample 2","name":"POLY_TOT","value":7}]]

var obj = {}
//Loop main array
var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  //Loop each group array to get objects
  e.forEach(function(a) {
    //Check if current object name exists as key in obj
    if (!obj[a.name]) {
      //If it doesn't create new object as its value and store it in obj
      obj[a.name] = {group: a.name,[a.group]: a.value}
      //push value of that object in result array of reduce or r
      r.push(obj[a.name])
    } else {
    //If it already exists in obj then assign new property to it
      Object.assign(obj[a.name], {[a.group]: a.value})
    }
  })
  // Return accumulator or result array
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happening here. That will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.